# Aggregating a time series in Pandas given a window size

Tags: pandas

Lets say I have this data

```
a = pandas.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])

a
Out[313]: 
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
5    6
6    7
7    8
dtype: int64
```

I would like aggregate data which groups data `n` rows at a time and sums them up. So if `n=2` the new series would look like `{3,7,11,15}`.

Comment: you mean {3,7,11,15} ? Also what if there are odd number of elements ? How do you plan to add them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
In [39]: a.groupby(a.index//2).sum()
Out[39]:
0     3
1     7
2    11
3    15
dtype: int64

In [41]: a.index//2
Out[41]: Int64Index([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], dtype='int64')
```

n=3

```
In [42]: n=3

In [43]: a.groupby(a.index//n).sum()
Out[43]:
0     6
1    15
2    15
dtype: int64

In [44]: a.index//n
Out[44]: Int64Index([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2], dtype='int64')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use pandas [rolling mean](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.rolling_mean.html) and get it like the following:
if `n` is your interval:

```
sums = list(a.rolling(n).sum()[n-1::n])

# Optional !!!
rem = len(a)%n
if rem != 0:
    sums.append(a[-rem:].sum())
```

The first line perfectly adds the rows if the data can be properly divided into groups, else, we also can add the remaining sum (depends on your preference).
For e.g., in the above case, if `n=3`, then you may want to get either `{6, 15, 15}` or just `{6, 15}`. The code above is for the former case. And skipping the optional part gives you just `{6, 15}`.